# How to convert this T-Sql to linq

Tags: c#, linq

i write this tsql Query

```
((SELECT Id,[Mesc]
      ,[Line]
      ,[Unit]
      ,[Discription]
      ,[InvQty]
      ,[LastDateNil]
      ,[StCode]
      ,[PlanCode]
      ,[MIN]
      ,[MAX]
      ,[LastDateConsum]
      ,[PbsNo]
      ,[PbsDate]
      ,[PbsQty]
      ,[PbsQtyRec]
      ,[DateDelay]
      ,[TypeRequest]
      ,[HeaderId]
  FROM [MyMaterialDB].[dbo].[Report2]
  WHERE headerid IN(SELECT HeaderId FROM [MyMaterialDB].[dbo].[Report2] WHERE line='I'))

  Order by Mesc,Line,unit
```

i want convert this to linq, but i'm biginet in linq, please help me. thanks all.

Comment: why do you want to switch to linq without learning it first? at least basics?

Comment: What have you tried and failed (in "failed" I mean every unexpected behavior that's known to you. So if you update question before it's closed let's know exactly how has failed)?

Answer (score 3):

Unless it's a typo, the inner select isn't needed:

```
SELECT [Id], [Mesc], <etc>
  FROM [MyMaterialDB].[dbo].[Report2]
  WHERE line='I'
  ORDER BY Mesc,Line,unit
```

So your LINQ would be something like:

```
report2
  .Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Mesc, <etc> })
  .Where(x => x.line == "I")
  .OrderBy(x => x.Mesc)
  .ThenBy(x => x.Line)
  .ThenBy(x => x.unit)
```

(NB off the top of my head - might need correcting slightly).

Comment: stusmith : thanks for help me, but my Query is SELECT [Id], [Mesc], <etc>
  FROM [MyMaterialDB].[dbo].[Report2]
  WHERE headerid  in(HeaderId FROM [Report2] WHERE line='I')

Comment: Yep, I don't think the inner select is needed: it's a join to the same table (`Report2` and `Report2`).